# Многостраничное приложение на Vue + Django RESTful API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

Как организовать проект на `Vue` с несколькими страницами что-бы пользователь при загрузки страницы не выкачивал все приложение или это не сказывалось на производительности, хочется посмотреть примеры кода и советы как лучше это организовать? 
Является данный проблема критичной для `Vue` приложений? Можно жить допустим с 2000 страниц и использовать `Vue-router` без потери производительности?

Как пример, список страниц:

```
\  # главная страница
\login 
\user\  # все пользователи
\user\<id>\  # пользователь
\post\  # список постов
\post\<id>\  # пост 
\settings\  # настройки
\user\<id>\post\  # список постов пользователя
```

Comment: смотрите в сторону `webpack module` , можно разбить кодовую базу на модули (login, user, post и т.д.), и при переходе на соответствующий роут будет подгружаться нужный модуль. Или использовать [Асинхронные компоненты](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

Comment: @MrFylypenko спасибо, почитаю, но вообще немного удивляет что либо я не так ищу либо это не такая проблема как я думаю, но очень мало информации как строить приложения с подобным подходом